# Handle all sub-events in one place in c# using delegate/event?

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

Let's assume that we have MissionA, MissionB and we want broadcast when any mission started. How can I achieve that in c#?

Something like below (They are separate in different .cs files):

Mission general (in MissionGeneral.cs):

```
namespace MissionGeneral
{
    public class MissionGeneral
    {
        public delegate void MissionStartedEvent(string name);
        public event MissionStartedEvent OnMissionStart;
    }
}
```

Sub mission A (in MissionA.cs):

```
namespace MissionA
{
    public class MissionA
    {
        public delegate void MissionStartedEvent(string name);
        public event MissionStartedEvent OnMissionStart;
        protected virtual void HandleMissionStartedEvent()
        {
            OnMissionStart?.Invoke("MissionA");
        }
    }
}
```

Sub mission B (in MissionB.cs):

```
namespace MissionB
{
    public class MissionB
    {
        public delegate void MissionStartedEvent(string name);
        public event MissionStartedEvent OnMissionStart;
        protected virtual void HandleMissionStartedEvent()
        {
            OnMissionStart?.Invoke("MissionB");
        }
    }
}
```

Broadcaster (in Broadcaster.cs):

```
using MissionGeneral;    

namespace Broadcaster
{
    public class Broadcaster
    {
        public MissionGeneral mission = new MissionGeneral();

        public Broadcaster()
        {
            mission.OnMissionStart += (_name) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"This is {_name}");
                if (_name == "MissionA") Console.WriteLine("Additional MissionA info");
                else if (_name == "MissionB") Console.WriteLine("Additional MissionB info");
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If missionA and mission B herit from missionGeneral, you will have the same event for the two mission. You do need to declare 2 events

Comment: You shouldn't be using the base type at all if you actually need to treat the two types entirely differently.  Either make the base type have all of the members needed for what you need to do and use it, or don't use a base type at all because you can't actually generalize what you want.  Trying to do half and half gives you the worst of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is to:

1. Pass to the event hanlder the object that triggered the event:

   ```
   public delegate void MissionStartedEvent(MissionGeneral sender);
   public event MissionStartedEvent OnMissionStart;
   ```
2. Let the object itself provide the needed information to the handler:

   ```
   public Broadcaster()
   {
       mission.OnMissionStart += (sender) =>
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"This is {sender.Name}");
           Console.WriteLine($"Additional info: {sender.AdditionalInfo}");
       };
   }
   ```

If each subtype of `MissionGeneral` must have a specific implementation of `Name`, `AdditionalInfo` or whatever, then make those methods `virtual` in the base class and override them when necessary.

If its the case that you need to access subtype specific members in the event handler, then you can always pattern match (not a great scenario but still leaps and bounds better than discerning types based on a string):

```
 mission.OnMissionStart += (sender) =>
 {
     Console.WriteLine($"This is {sender.Name}");

     switch (sender) {
         case MissionA a:
             Console.WriteLine(a.SomeSpecificMissionAMember);
             break;
         case MissionB b:
             Console.WriteLine(b.SomeSpecificMissionAMember);
             break; }
 }
```

Comment: Mission should have same members in my case. But how to correctly declare mission in Broadcaster? Both MissionA and MIssionB are different classes, Is that the only way is to use inheritance (from MissionGeneral)?